# Fragment Communicating With Main Activity

Tags: java, android, fragment, communication

I have a `Fragment` which displays content for my app, but I also have a `Spinner` below the `Fragment`.

I want something to happen in the `Fragment` when the value of the `Spinner` is changed. So my question is how does the `MainActivity` communicate with the `Fragment`?

Comment: post your full code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `MainActivity` to communicate with one the `Fragment`s in its `FragmentManager`, you'd access it with either `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()`. I.e.

```
MyFrag frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container);
```

or

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my_frag_tag");
```

Comment: What about if it is in a ViewPager? @PPartisan

Comment: @ChiragGalaiya Then that's a bit trickier. You can use the method outlined in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043469/controlling-back-button-inside-fragment/35044012#35044012) (also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182919/call-fragment-function-over-activity/34183721#34183721)) for an approach that involves cycling through every `Fragment` in your `FragmentManager`, or use an `EventBus`